# Post-processing goal: three different exposures?

Tags: post-processing, landscape, multiple-exposure, sunset, exposure-correction

I took a photo yesterday on Roan Mountain, on the AT.

In the foreground is an overgrown meadow. Midground is a nearby mountain, dark in contrast with the sun setting just over it. In the background, more cascading mountains.

This was shot in RAW on a Canon 40D and I'm doing post-processing in LR 4.4.1.

I'm no expert, but it seems to me that each zone needs a separate exposure level. But it could be that I need to adjust the lighting in some other way... any help would be appreciated.

"RAW" exposure... I'd probably use something around this lighting for the mid-ground mountain-and-flare:
[image]

Adjust exposure to +1.9 for foreground:

[image]

Sky and background mountains are mostly visible around -0.4:

[image]

Any thoughts appreciated... both about post-processing and what I need to do next time to make this easier.

Comment: Next time take three ( or more ) photos.  Each exposed for the area or zone you want and combine the images  in post. I do not do it so i leave the *how to* to others. Research **"HDR Photography"**  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_imaging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is HDR photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/what-is-hdr-photography)

Comment: Also note that many other methodologies fall under the wider umbrella of *High Dynamic Range Imaging* than those mentioned in the answers to the linked questions above that are directly related to 32-bit floating point commonly referred to as *HDR*. Layering and masking, for example, or what is commonly called *exposure fusion*, for another example, are two such techniques.

Comment: Related: [Multiple exposures vs. adjusting exposure of single RAW?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42190/15871) and [What's the difference between “Fake HDR” and real, bracketed exposure HDR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80591/15871) and [What is the difference between Digital Blending & HDR technique](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45634/15871)

Comment: Additionally, it looks like you might have been using a "protective" filter on the front of your lens. If that is the case, remove it to reduce the effects of lens flare and reduction in contrast.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer to this, but it will encompass using the grad filter tool in Lightroom...if you want to get started on learning about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are multiple ways to do this, my preferred approach is exposure blending. You basically take multiple exposures from LR and blend them together in Photoshop using luminosity masks. You may not even need 3 exposures to get a satisfactory product if you start with the right settings in LR to generate the first image. I took the 3rd exposure you provided and used dodging and burning in PS to bring out the foreground highlights and darken the background. It may be possible to do the same thing in LR (it has a dodge and burn capability) but it would require protecting areas and focusing on specific tonal values -  and I am not an expert on these.

[image: Roan Mtn .png file with dodging and burning]

If this is not enough light in the foreground, you can overlay the brighter image with the darker image and use luminosity masks to bring through the lighter parts as desired. I tried this, but the lighter image is a bit blown out - it is so bright that some of the detail in the foreground is lost.

Greg Benz is an expert at this and has several free youtube courses as well as a master course on exposure blending. He also has a number of free tutorials on lightroom and photoshop settings to enhance color and texture. He has a specific tutorial on HDR versus luminosity masks that may help answer your question.
[HDR Vs. Luminosity Masks by Greg Benz](https://gregbenzphotography.com/photography-tips/hdr-vs-luminosity-masks)